# How to give the absolute path of a file in location " C: \Users\V\Downloads\automate.csv'' in karate Robot?

Tags: karate

When a file is downloaded it is placed in a location C: \Users\V\Downloads\automate.csv
As this is an automated test which is executed in any computer this C:\Users\V\ path information varies. I did tried with options There are options like karate.toAbsolute('relativepath.csv') but this points to the only the files in a solution.

Let me the the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You mean Karate UI right? The only suggestions I have are:

- Try to use the API testing capabilities: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54421411/143475
- Or you can explore how to change the browser settings and the "user data dir" (this needs you to do research): https://stackoverflow.com/a/63337793/143475
- Also see: [How to save XLSX file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33553611/143475)